# Adding a second loop

Tags: c

I want to add a second loop to my program, in which I let the user enter an number **x** in each loop and form the sum over the entered numbers. the result of this code is 378 but must be for example 378+**x**=380

```
int main()
{
    int i;
    int sum = 0;

    for (i = 1; i <= 27; i++) {
        sum += i;
    }
    printf("%d\n", sum);        

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Why do you need a loop? Do you want the user to type in one number or several?

Comment: And why don’t you just do what you have described?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or add additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it’s hard to tell exactly what you're asking. See the [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) page for help clarifying this question.

Comment: After the end of the loop I have to output the sum as a result again. I dont know which loop to add

Answer (score -1):

You write a loop inside your loop and add a scanf.

```
int i, j;
int sum = 0;
for (int i = 0; i <= 27; i++) { 
    for (j = 0; j < 10; j++) {
       int x= 0;
       scanf ("%d", &x); 
       sum += x;
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

If you add a second loop you will need to input y*x inputs where y is the frequency of 2nd loop.
The code you may be looking for is

```
int main () {

int i,x;
int sum = 0;    

for(i = 1; i <= 27; i++)
    {
    scanf("%d",&x);
    sum += i+x;
    }      
    printf("%d\n", sum);        

return 0;
}
```